# Why won't this particular code work for a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a binary search tree. I already have the code for a binary tree and I've tried multiple times to insert numbers into the binary search tree and print them out inorder. The code does nothing ie, nothing comes up on the console. Could someone tell me why is that?

```
class BST {
    Node root;

    BST(){
        root=null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        BST tree = new BST(); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,23); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,0); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,1); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,4); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,12); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,58); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,122); 
        tree.inorder(tree.root); 
    }

    Node insert(Node root, int data) { 
        if (root == null) { 
            root = new Node(data); 
            return root; 
        } 
        if (data < root.data) 
            root.left = insert(root.left, data); 
        else if (data > root.data) 
            root.right = insert(root.right, data); 
        return root; 
    } 

    void inorder(Node root) { 
        if (root != null) { 
            inorder(root.left); 
            System.out.println(root.data); 
            inorder(root.right); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your root node will always be null.

I recommend you to read some materials on 'Java method - passed by value vs passed by reference' first. https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/learn-java-does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html

```
class BST {
    Node root;

    BST(){
        root=null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        BST tree = new BST(); 
        tree.root=tree.insert(tree.root,23); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,0); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,1); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,4); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,12); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,58); 
        tree.insert(tree.root,122); 
        tree.inorder(tree.root); 
    }

    Node insert(Node root, int data) { 
        if (root == null) { 
            root = new Node(data); 
            return root; 
        } 
        if (data < root.data) 
            root.left = insert(root.left, data); 
        else if (data > root.data) 
            root.right = insert(root.right, data); 
        return root; 
    } 

    void inorder(Node root) { 
        if (root != null) { 
            inorder(root.left); 
            System.out.println(root.data); 
            inorder(root.right); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks jackycflau  I do appreciate it, and thanks for the link. I read the info and will be taking a more in depth look at Java methods.